# How to make an anchor clickable again in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, anchor

For some reason i turn off the click event for an anchor using jquery .off() function

Now for other reasons, i want to re-establish the anchor to be clickable again.

I use the anchor to show/hide extra text on the page. The href is equal to javascript:void(0).

So i somehow want to detect the click without specify any code in the second argument of .on() function.

i disabled it using

```
 $(this).off('click');
```

How the other way around work ?

Thanks!

Comment: $(this).on('click', function(e){
//event fired

});

Comment: Thanks! The point is that i just want to re-establish the click behaviour. I don't want to add a specific code. Basically i have href="javascript:void(0)" and i use the anchor to hide/show some extra text

Comment: So accept my answer!!
Cheers!!

Comment: Does not work in my case. See edited question...

Comment: Remember - on() only works specifically with those elements you have disabled with off()

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) it again just like you switch `off` and `on` the light :P:

```
$(this).on('click', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The point is that i just want to re-establish the click behaviour. I don't want to add a specific code. Basically i have href="javascript:void(0)" and i use the anchor to hide/show some extra text

Comment: Is it because you're using $(this) as your selector when you need to do something like $('a').on('click', function()...?

Comment: no i i use the .on('click') on an anchor with specific class ".deactivated". I add this class after i do the .off(). Basically i detect the ".deactivated" element so i can enable it again. The detection work because i apply other functions on it like show()...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).on('click', function(e){
//event fired
location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

your anchor works like a normal anchor tag

Answer for questionnaire only:

```
$(this).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').toggle();
    });
```